# In GWT, how to create a Style object and associate it with a Widget WITHOUT using a CSS file and WITHOUT UiBinder

Tags: css, gwt

I would just like to create a Style object and associate it with a Widget, all in Java.

It is possible to create a Style object like that: 
   Style style = new Style();

It is possible to link a Widget with a Style using: 
   FlowPanel panel = new FlowPanel();
   panel.setStyleName("myStyle");

But you need "myStyle" to exist in some CSS file.

It would be nice to be able to do:
   Style style = new Style("myStyle");

I would like to do everything in Java and avoid the CSS or UiBinder file.

Thank you !

Comment: I wouldn't go that route. Your code will become messy. I think that UIBinder + CSS + Java is much cleaner and easier to maintain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to access the Style element by using

```
someUiObject.getElement().getStyle()
```

and then manipulate the style there.

Comment: You're so right !  I'm new to GWT and I was looking at the forest: didn't see the tree right there!